# Is a 5V DC Voltage @ 30mA applied, applied to water, unsafe?

Tags: electricity, water, conductivity

As my question states, I have 5V DC, with an input current of 30mA, being applied across two exposed metal electrodes which are inserted into water.  I am trying to measure the conductivity of water for a scientific experiment.

Would there be any concerns about the safety of this system, in case someone touches the water?

Comment: Hi Gary. Is there a reason for 30mA? Instead of "conductivity", could you measure resistance? Latter should use much less current. Try this with a multimeter set to Ohms and a small dish. Add water and a pinch of table salt.

Comment: Yo don't get to define both the output voltage and output current from your power supply. You choose one, and the load resistance determines the other (depending on the capability of your supply to maintain the parameter you chose).

Comment: Sorry, should have clarified better.  30mA is the maximum input current into the system.

Answer (score 2):

It is definitely safe. But make sure that your power supply doesn't have a risk of increasing the voltage to abnormal level or risk of electrical isolation failings (between the output and mains). Also earth your power supply properly.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a certified power supply mounted in a location where it is safe from splashes or ingress of water then that is no more dangerous than touching the metal parts of the connector on a USB phone charger. That is, it is safe.

Answer (score 1):

No - that is generally safe as long as the voltage is not going to inncrease beyond that. 5V cannot drive enough current through the body to cause damage even if the skin is broken.
It is even safe if someone sticks their head between the two electrodes. I have experimented with tDCS at 9V and saline electrodes attached to the head. That has trouble pushing more than 2mA.

However, make sure that the PSU cannot fail to a much higher voltage eg mains.